# Finger reader for hp Probook6560b not recogized

Tags: hp

I have Ubuntu 11.10 64bit on HP ProBook 6560b. all my hardwars are recongized, but the finger print is not recongized. in the driver page of HP ProBook6560b i dont found the driver,

my device ID is:
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader

please help m

Answer (score 1):

You should get to this link. May this will solve your problem:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ThinkFinger
- http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/04/get-your-fingerprint-reader-to-work-in.html

**Edit :** Hey type this code on your terminal : `lsusb`. There is a packaged called fprint available in this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint) However, if your device id does not appear in the list of "Supported" then your fingerprint is not supported. There is a [Bug #285089](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/285089) which details similar issue.

Comment: i still the same problem, i have the error: bassel@IT-BASSEL:~$ sudo tf-tool --acquire
Could not locate any suitable fingerprints matched with available hardware.
[sudo] password for bassel: 

ThinkFinger 0.3 (http://thinkfinger.sourceforge.net/)
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007 Timo Hoenig <thoenig@suse.de>

Initializing...USB device not found

Comment: It seems that your hardware is not detected by ubuntu. I don't know how to fix this but BTW fingerprint is not so much important....

Comment: you are right thnak you very much for your help